# Cannot run mmc.exe except from the command line after "Run as Administrator"

Tags: permissions, windows-10, mmc

I'm running Windows 10 (1803)

If I try to run any `msc` (I.e. Device Manager) directly (by searching for "Device Manager" and clicking the find result) I get the error ...

[image: Error]

However, if I open `cmd` with "Run as administrator", I can open it normally with  `devmgmt.msc`. This system is not on a domain. This account is in the admin group.

Logging in with a different account with admin permissions results in the same error.

I'm not sure where to check, or what to correct. Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when Windows can't confirm that the certificates used by the operating system are valid.

Check the date/time of your computer, and that you are not using a pre-relase or an Insider Windows Build. You can start `winver.exe` that no expiration date is displayed.

If you use an official build and the date/time is correct, you can use this command (as administrator): `SFC /Scannow` so that Windows can check if the system files are corrupted.

Additionally, check if you can find interesting informations by clicking on the "Show information about the publisher's certificate" link.

Comment: Your mention of the certificate was the clue. It turns out the cryptsvc was disabled. I re-enabled it, and the issue went away. Thanks for the help!